# Storing generic objects in Swift Array

Tags: generics, swift

Wrote the following little test:

```
class Model { }
class SubModel : Model {}
class Collection<T: Model> {}

let collection = Collection<SubModel>()
var collections = [Collection]() // Also tried [Collection<Model>]() 
collections.append(collection)
```

The compiler fails on the append call. The message is: 'SubModel' is not identical to 'Model'.
Based on my experience in all other languages I have used with generics, this should work. As a Collection of type SubMode should always be coercible to a Collection of type Model.
Anyone run into this? Workarounds?

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because Swift does not support [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in respect of generic type parameters.

For example:

```
class Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}
```

`Cat` is clearly a subtype of `Animal`. However, this does not mean that, for instance, `Array<Cat>` is a subtype of `Array<Animal>`. In a language that supports covariance for generic type parameters, such as C#, `Array<Cat>` would be a subtype of `Array<Animal>`.

In your specific example, you can use a protocol and a *non-generic* Collection class to get around this limitation. Other situations might require more creativity.

```
protocol Collectible {}
class Model : Collectible {}
class SubModel : Model {}

class Collection {
    func append(element: Collectible) {
        // blah
    }
}

var collection = Collection()
collection.append(Model())
collection.append(SubModel())
var collections = [collection]
```

Actually, in your case, you could just make the element of `Collection` be a `Model`, i.e., `func append(element: Model)`, but I did it this way to stress that protocols can sometimes be used to get around covariance limitations.